# Can oral sex cause throat cancer?

Tags: sexuality, cancer, epidemiology

(somebody had to ask this)

Micheal Douglas, who was diagnosed with throat cancer in 2010, said in a [recent interview with the Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/film/2013/jun/02/michael-douglas-oral-sex-cancer):

> Asked whether he now regretted his years of smoking and drinking, usually thought to be the cause of the disease, Douglas replied: “No. Because without wanting to get too specific, this particular cancer is caused by HPV [human papillomavirus], which actually comes about from cunnilingus.”

So the question arises: does it?

To be slightly more specific, to nail several possible variants on his claim with a single question and to put the results in context let me ask the question this way: Does oral sex (cunnilingus or fellatio) contribute to the risk of oral cancer? Is the risk significant in the context of other causes of this class of cancers?

Comment: I am more interested in his later claim that it also cures it :p

Comment: @chad I wish... Seriously, though, I suspect that claim warrants a separate question. Go ahead and ask it.

Comment: @matt_black - I think that the claim "And if you have it, cunnilingus is also the best cure for it." was made in jest.

Comment: I would upvote this, were I not male :D

Answer (score 24):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_and_neck_cancer#Human_papillomavirus, retrieved 2013-06-04 (Text is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike License) says,

> Recent evidence is accumulating pointing to a viral origin for some head and neck cancers. [(ref)](http://www.health.am/cr/head-and-neck-cancer/)
>
> Human papillomavirus (HPV), in particular HPV16, is a causal factor for some head and neck squamous cell carcinoma (HNSCC).([ref](http://www.la-press.com/redirect_file.php?fileId=1510&filename=CMENT-Moss-et-al&fileType=pdf%29%28http://dx.doi.org/10.1056/NEJMoa065497)) Approximately 15 to 25% of HNSCC contain genomic DNA from HPV,([ref](http://cebp.aacrjournals.org/cgi/pmidlookup?view=long&pmid=15734974)) and the association varies based on the site of the tumor, especially HPV-positive oropharyngeal cancer, with highest distribution in the tonsils, where HPV DNA is found in (45 to 67%) of the cases,([ref](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1860277)) less often in the hypopharynx (13%–25%), and least often in the oral cavity (12%–18%) and larynx (3%–7%).([ref](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0142%2819970201%2979:3%3C595::AID-CNCR24%3E3.0.CO;2-Y))
>
> Some experts estimate that while up to 50% of cancers of the tonsil may be infected with HPV, only 50% of these are likely to be caused by HPV (as opposed to the usual tobacco and alcohol causes). The role of HPV in the remaining 25-30% is not yet clear.([ref](http://jco.ascopubs.org/cgi/content/abstract/JCO.2004.00.3335v1)) **Oral sex is not risk free and can result in HPV-related cancer.**([ref](http://www.oralcancerfoundation.org/facts/pdf/hpv_Infection.pdf))

Comment: A good answer, but still lacks the context around the risks of cancers and different varieties of HPV. A little discussion of that context would make it a great answer.